# How to make a before/after treatment plot in R and then add it to a layout function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, layout

I have a couple of issues with a before/after treatment plot in R I need to fix.

As you can see, I had to call the Before variable **ABefore**, because the plot prints the variable in alphabetical order, however, I do not know how to make it better.

The most important thing is that the boxplot and the ggplot are not being printed in the layout previously specified, and I do not know why.

Do you have any solutions that might work?

Here is the code

````
if(!require(ggpubr)){install.packages("ggpubr")
  library(ggpubr)}
if(!require(tidyr)){install.packages("tidyr")
  library(tidyr)}
if(!require(magrittr)){install.packages("magrittr")
  library(magrittr)}

ABefore <- c(7,13,4,0,9,5,7,1,8,13,2,13)
After <- c(1,7,6,0,6,2,2,1,8,7,4,4)
Ind <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
aggrs <- data.frame(Ind,ABefore,After)

layout(matrix(c(1,2)),heights=c(1,1.5))
layout.show(2)
boxplot(Before+After, horizontal = TRUE, col = "blue", main = "Agressivity Before-After")
aggrs %>%
  gather('stage', 'value', ABefore, After)  %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = stage, y = value, group = Ind)) +
  theme_classic()+
  geom_line(linetype = 2) + 
  geom_point(colour = "red") ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ggplot automatically changes character variables into alphabetically ordered factors. To override this, you can manually make the character variable into a factor with the correct order of the levels.

This would be a ggplot solution

```
Before <- c(7,13,4,0,9,5,7,1,8,13,2,13)
After <- c(1,7,6,0,6,2,2,1,8,7,4,4)
Ind <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
aggrs <- data.frame(Ind,Before,After)


aggrs %>%
  gather('stage', 'value', Before, After)  %>%
  mutate(stage  = factor(stage, levels = c("Before", "After"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = stage, y = value, group = Ind)) +
  theme_classic()+
  geom_line(linetype = 2) + 
  geom_point(colour = "red")
```

To make a ggplot boxplot

```
aggrs %>%
  gather('stage', 'value', Before, After)  %>%
  mutate(stage  = factor(stage, levels = c("Before", "After"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = stage, y = value)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_boxplot()
```

To combine the two (if that what you want)

```
aggrs %>%
  gather('stage', 'value', Before, After)  %>%
  mutate(stage  = factor(stage, levels = c("Before", "After"))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  theme_classic()+
  geom_line(aes(x = stage, y = value, group = Ind), linetype = 2) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = stage, y = value, group = Ind), colour = "red") +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = stage, y = value), alpha = .4)
```